# Executing parent function on child close event

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm facing a boring issue here. I need to call a function on the parent window inside the close event of the child window. My code is like this:

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnPlay").click(function(){
        ShowPopup("URL", 600, 600, DoSomeStuff);

    });
});
function DoSomeStuff(){
    // Do some stuff
}
function ShowPopup(url, width, height, closeCallback){
    var options = "resizable=yes, status=no, location=no, menubar=no, width= " + width + ",height=" + height;
    var w = window.open(url, "_blank", options );
    w.onunload = function(){ 
        // INVOKE DoSomeStuff of the parent window
        console.log("X");
    }

}
```

But seems that the **onunload** event doesn't get called! What might be wrong?

Comment: is the pop up in a different domain?

Comment: @epascarello No, same domain!

Answer (score 0):

you're very close i think.

try:

```
function ShowPopup(url, width, height, closeCallback){
    var options = "resizable=yes, status=no, location=no, menubar=no, width= " + width + ",height=" + height;
    var w = window.open(url, "_blank", options );
    w.onunload = function(){ 
        closeCallback();
        console.log("X");
    }
}
```

Comment: But the message isn't getting printed to the console. onunload is not getting called!

Comment: ah apologies. I read your code but didn't spot the last line, so I assumed your issue was how to call the method. Your problem is probably that browsers handle the unload event in different ways. WHat browser are you using?